# Error trying to check item out of ArrayList bounds, but unsure of alternative

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm building a small program for a MOOC which will combine two Integer arraylists, but remove any duplicate numbers. My logic, I believe, is sound - but it seems JAVA doesn't have the functionality to solve the problem the way I had in mind. Here's the logic: first add all items to arraylist, then sort them ascending, then check from beginning to end if the item before each check is the same, if so remove the item before and continue checking.

The problem is, i assume, that it tries to check arraylist.get(-1) and encounters an error (as it should) && **I am unable to start checking from item 1, because it won't let me pre-define x as 1**. If the former is the case, can anyone point out where I'm wrong or suggest an alternative for me, if the latter - how do I pre-define x as 1 and still use the loop? Here's my code:

```
public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> uno, ArrayList<Integer> due) {
        int index = (uno.size() - 1);
        uno.addAll(index, due);
        Collections.sort(uno);
        for (int x : uno) {
            if (uno.get(x) == uno.get(x - 1)) {
                uno.remove(x - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at SmartCombining.smartCombine(SmartCombining.java:11)
at SmartCombining.main(SmartCombining.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Why are you inserting `due` *before* the last element of `uno`?

Comment: Java can solve your problem, but if you start out believing that your *logic is sound*, and that Java is the problem, you're going to have a lot of problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop iterates the *values*, not the *indexes*.

Since you want to compare two values, you can use a normal `for` loop. In your case, since you use `x - 1`, you have to start the loop at `1`.

```
for (int x = 1; x < uno.size(); x++) {
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I tested this and it worked. Never completely abandon the old for the new.